# Suddenly I lost my VMware Player Linux ip , why?

Tags: networking, vmware-player

I installed CentOs 5.8 on VMware player version 3.1.2 that running on windows xp

Everything was working great I used bridged network configuration and I got ip (probably from the network DHCP )

But suddenly yesterday I started VMware and I could not connect , when I do ifconfig  –a I don’t see my old ip , in fact I don’t see any ip

What can be wrong here ?

Comment: Mostly irrelevant, but there isn't a 5.8 release of CentOS yet.  You probably mean 4.8 or 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

It happens from time to time; just do a 'service network restart' as the ROOT user from the command line (Terminal/Console) and DHCP will assign you a new lease.

Andrew

Comment: ok i did what you said and it gives me error on restarting saying :
Determinig ip information for eth0 ... failed:no link present. check cable ?  
the thing is that i have network in my pc and every thing is working fine

Comment: In VMWARE player which network adaptor have you bound to? It's not a simple case of setting the machine up to run from your eth0 on your host, when, now you're on wireless which is presented as eth1 ?